# for in loop returns wrong objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, for-in-loop

I have a for in loop where I do not quite get the objects I expect to get.

I have a CCLayer class called `MainLayer` where I add children of class `MyUniqueClass`. However if I try to get all `MyUniqueClass` objects, I get other CCNode objects as well. Here's what I do in `MainLayer`:

```
for (MyUniqueClass *mUC in self.children){

        NSLog(@"%@", mUC); //Here I get all kinds of objects 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to figure out why the CCNode objects are there. Somehow they've been added as children.

Or just ignore that and do this to filter out other node classes:

```
Class uniqueClass = [MyUniqueClass class];
for (MyUniqueClass *mUC in self.children)
{
    if ([mUC isKindOfClass:uniqueClass])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", mUC);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have CCNode objects there intentionally. I thought the for in loop gives me all MyUniqueClass objects. If it gives me all CCNode objects what use does it have anyway ? I could've iterated through the children without the for in loop and use the `-isKindOfClass` method in it.

Comment: The for in loop is just a fast iterator. That's all.

Comment: for in returns all objects in self.children. Casting the receiving pointer to MyUniqueClass* doesn't change which objects you get.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to believe that typing the loop variable as `MyUniqueClass *` will cause the loop to only cover objects belonging to that class. That isn't how fast enumeration works. It doesn't interact with the type checker at all. Giving a static type to the loop variable just lets the compiler do type checking on the things you do in the loop body (so it can warn you if, say, you're accidentally using a text field like a text view) and lets you access the object's properties with dot syntax. If you want to only operate on objects of a certain class, you'll have to explicitly check in your loop body [as shown by LearnCocos2D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11782602/50742).